# Contents of EAX in IDA Free?

Tags: ida, stack, crackme, strings, register

I am doing Level 2 of TryHackMe's REloaded reverse engineering challenges.

In the screen shot below, you can see I have found the string I want by hovering my mouse over EAX, however a good chunk is missing. How do I see the full string?

I have found that memory location in the stack view and underlined it in red, but I have no idea what to do next.

[image: IDA Free register help]

Comment: I think I figured it out. Copy the memory location from the register, then paste it into the long bar at the very bottom of IDA (it has a button called IDC at the far left) and press enter. After, click on the text IDC>WHAT_YOU_PASTED and it takes you to the correct place.

Comment: Just click the blue arrow next to the register name.

Comment: @Qwark Appreciated, also mind checking this follow up question? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31820/where-is-the-xor-operation